# Offline tracking with gtag.js

Tags: gtag.js

With ga.js I could track offline activity and send to my custom server or store in localhist by overriding the sendHitTask.

Like this:
https://www.google.se/amp/s/www.simoahava.com/amp/analytics/track-users-who-are-offline-in-google-analytics/

How can I achieve the same with gtag.js so I can customize where and in what data structure to send hits?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since you've asked this question, but I wanted to share my findings regarding this matter:

Although gtag.js doesn't support sendHitTask (or an equivalent, as far as I know) it does support the `transport_url` parameter.

With this parameter you can set an alternate Transport URL to send the data to. It's originally designed to work with [Server Side Tracking](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/server-side/send-data) but it can also be used to capture requests to /g/collect/ or /r/collect/ endpoints on your own server.

I know it only partially resolves your issue, because you can't fully decide where to send the data. But at least it allows to alter the server where the data is sent.

Hope it helps!